# How significant are health benefits from smoking in moderation as opposed to smking immoderately?

Tags: risks, smoking, tobacco

First of all it is obvious that the single best thing a tobacco smoker can do is to quit smoking entirely and I'm not going to argue with this.

However, in practice, many smokers can't / won't / don't want to quit entirely. Instead, they strive to keep their habit moderate, although the definite of 'moderate' varies from person to person and may range from only smoking light cigarettes, only smoking 1-2 cigarettes a day, only smoking a pack a day (as opposed to 2 packs or even more), etc. Ignoring the size of the smoker's wallet, what can one gain from trying to moderate one's smoking as opposed to smoking immoderately?

### It is claimed that it matters far more if a person is smoking than how much a person is smoking

> Researchers say that people who smoke five cigarettes a day are doing almost as much damage to their lungs as people who smoke 30 cigarettes a day.
> They say it takes “light” smokers about 1 year to develop as much lung damage as “heavy” smoking does in 9 months.

Source: [‘Social’ Smoking Does Almost as Much Damage to Your Lungs as ‘Heavy’ Smoking](https://www.healthline.com/health-news/smoking-5-cigarettes-a-day-isnt-much-better-than-smoking-2-packs) on Healthline

> Smoking one to four cigarettes a day, for example, increases the risk of heart disease almost as much as smoking a pack a day.

Source: [Light and social smoking carry cardiovascular risks](https://web.archive.org/web/20220810124718/https://www.health.harvard.edu/newsletter_article/light-and-social-smoking-carry-cardiovascular-risks)  on Harvard Health

> A new study that I conducted with other nursing and health services researchers has found that those who enjoy the occasional cigarette in social situations are risking their health just as much as the person who smokes a pack or more a day.

Source: [Why social smoking can be just as bad for you as daily smoking](https://theconversation.com/why-social-smoking-can-be-just-as-bad-for-you-as-daily-smoking-79968) on The Conversation

> When analyzed according to the tar rating of cigarette smoked, the results of the study showed the risk of lung cancer death was greatest for smokers of high-tar unfiltered cigarettes. The risk of lung cancer death was no different among smokers of medium-, low-, and very low-tar cigarettes.
>
> These findings do not come as a complete surprise to researchers. A previous study showed smokers of low-tar cigarettes compensate for the decrease in tar level by changing their inhalation pattern. By blocking ventilation holes in the filter, increasing the drag time, holding the puff longer and deeper, or smoking more cigarettes, addicted smokers may maintain their nicotine intake (and exposure to carcinogens) with low-tar cigarettes.

Source: [Low-tar cigarettes are not a safer choice](https://web.archive.org/web/20211117193200/https://www.health.harvard.edu/cancer/low-tar-cigarettes-are-not-a-safer-choice) on Harvard Health; interestingly, this seems to be at odds with my previous citations, since this claims that lower tar content in light cigarettes is offset by larger consumption quantities, but my earlier citations say that consumption quantities are insignificant

Therefore, I understand that health risks of tobacco consumption follow an inverted J-shaped curve: the risks rise slowly with increasing quantity and strength of consumed tobacco products, but rise greatly when consumption goes from zero to non-zero. (This is unlike with alcohol)

### Moderate smoking means constant cravings

Now there are two citations I would provide, but I can't because I can't Google them now ;/ This pattern really sucks: I read something on Wikipedia or in a newspaper or maybe even in a more reputable source, remember it, then can't find it when I need the source.

Firstly: I read that light (or only occasional? I don't recall this part) smokers, who maintain they are not addicted, in fact also experience cravings, but they just suppress them.

Secondly: I read that even pack-a-day smokers suffer from reduced productivity, because 15 minutes after each cigarette is spent on remembering this cigarette and regretting it ended so soon and 15 minutes before each cigarette in spent on wanting to have another cigarette.

Just to not be completely empty-worded here, let me provide two citations I could find. What they say would fit well with the above:

> Smokers report higher levels of everyday stress. Several studies have monitored feelings of stress over time and found reduced stress after quitting.
>
> The deleterious mood effects of abstinence explain why people who smoke experience more daily stress than non-smokers and become less stressed when they quit smoking. Deprivation reversal also explains much of the arousal data, with deprived smokers being less vigilant and less alert than non-deprived smokers or non-smokers.

Source: [Health effects of tobacco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_effects_of_tobacco#Psychological) on Wikipedia

> Normal between-cigarettes discontinuation, in unrestricted smokers, causes mild but measurable nicotine withdrawal symptoms. These include mildly worse mood, stress, anxiety, cognition, and sleep, all of which briefly return to normal with the next cigarette. Smokers have worse mood than they would have if they were not nicotine-dependent; they experience normal moods only immediately after smoking.

Source: [Nicotine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicotine#Reinforcement_disorders) on Wikipedia

### Result: Quit or, failing that, smoke with no restrictions?

This strikes me as odd. It seems there are few benefits from trying to moderate one's smoking, but there is a very significant downside, namely almost non-stop withdrawal.

The conclusion that seems logical, however, is very counter-intuitive: a smoker should, first and foremost, quit, but if they won't quit, they should lose all restrictions? If a smoker spends 15 minutes after each cigarette regretting it ended, maybe they should smoke stronger cigarettes or smoke more vigorously? If a smoker spends 15 minutes before each cigarette, maybe they should smoke the next one 15 minutes earlier? Their health won't suffer that much more in comparison to the great harm they are already doing to their bodies, but their general quality of life should increase?

Where is my mistake? What am I failing to understand?

### Obligatory disclaimers

Disclaimer 1: I am not arguing a point, I understand that my thinking led to counter-intuitive and probably wrong results and I am not condoning smoking immoderately nor smoking at all. In an attempt to forestall the risk that someone takes my question literally and uses it as a (pseudo-scientific) justification of their unrestricted smoking, [here is a bunch of anecdotal evidence that unrestricted smoking can lead to crippling and eventually fatal diseases disturbingly early](https://www.medhelp.org/posts/Respiratory-Disorders/29-yr-old-girlfriend-has-emphysema/show/1217410).

Disclaimer 2: I have never smoked tobacco.

Comment: As a former smoker I don't believe the study you only remember that claims smokers spend 15 minutes before and after thinking about a cigarette. I'd have to see the study to even begin to believe that, and your question rather hinges on it being true.